# Не запускаются jar-файлы

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, товарищи.

Решил вот пойти по пути развития (одной Delphi сыт не будешь), и поставил NetBeans вместе со всеми JAVA-ништяками, которые мне посоветовал установить инсталер вышеупомянутой IDE.

Сконструировал, как полагается, незамысловатый "Hello World!". Но вот беда - моя форточка 7 не понимает, что делать с jar-файлами.

что сделал:

- настроил соответствия файлов: jar - Java (TM) Platform SE Binary
- залез в реестр и в папочке **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/jarfile/shell/open/command** увидел ключик со значением "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"  -jar "%1" %*.
- в той же мусорке нашел папочку **HKEY_CORRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/FIleExts/.jar** и в ней:
- - *OpenWithList*/ a = javaw.exe -jar
- - *OpenWIthList*/ MRUList = a
- - *OpenWIthProgids*/ jarfile = (двоичное значение нулевой длины)
- - *UserChoice*/ Progid = jarfile

В итоге видим, что все так, как говорит сделать [RTFM](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#troubleshooting), но чудо не происходит - при двойном клике по HelloWorldApp.jar созерцаем бездействие системы.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: всё.......

Comment: Эт тебе не Delphi :)

Comment: @Viacheslav, спасибо, вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: а из командной строки заводится?

Comment: вы перегружали комп после этого?

Comment: @jmu, мне перезагружать комп после каждой компиляции?  
После установки NetBeans и всего, что связано с Java, компютер перезагружался и выключался неоднократно.

Comment: имеется в виду после изменение реестра, java программам на перезагрузку плевать

Comment: @jmu, я ничего не менял в реестре. Если внимательно вчитаться в текст сабжа, то можно заметить, что я в реестре ничего не менял, а только смотрел его.
- 
да, и по поводу перезагрузки после компиляции - это был троллинг.

Comment: > настроил соответствия файлов: jar - Java (TM) Platform SE Binary

а в контексте работы с реестром как еще понимать слово "настроил" ? ну да ладно. я раньше настраивал реестр с той же целью. посмотрю может где завалялись файлики

Comment: @jmu, соответствия файлов настраиваются не только через реестр, но еще и через панель управления. После такой настройки, я полез проверять реестр. Я же написал, что сначала настроил, а потом залез в реестр.

Comment: мне больше интересна затея с запуском по двойному клику .jar файлов. Честно говоря я не понимаю зачем это нужно. Но вопрос у @teanЫЧ такой не стоит, поэтому я со своими мыслями пожалуй удалюсь...

тссс, никому не говорите, но я бы написал просто батник, запускающий .jar файлы


кстати, если Вы действительно делали всё по инструкции, может попробуете запустить с запущенной консолью(Хотя я уверен, Вы так уже пытались сделать, но с чем же только java не шутила)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала просто `java -jar <my.jar>`, если не работает, значит неправильно собран jar, если работает - значит что-то неладно с реестром Windows

**Update**

Только сейчас обратил внимание на этот ваш `javaw` в реестре. Дело в том, что: **javaw.exe** - это специальная неблокирующая и неконсольная версия команды. При запуске она не запускает консоли. Обычно нужна для запуска GUI приложений.

В вашем случае, ваш HelloWorld очевидно, консольный - это и есть причина того, что ничего не происходит. В реестре надо сделать ассоциацию **.jar** с **java.exe**

Answer (score 2):

А почему вы решили, что ничего не работает? Может она запускается и застревает или сразу же выходит. 
Как выглядит ваша Hello World программа? Может быть вы просто написали в main System.out.println(...) и больше ничего? Тогда вы, конечно, ничего не увидите. Для этого надо либо запускать с помощью java, а не javaw. Либо всё-таки делать какое-то окошко и в нём писать. А так оно просто пишется в никуда и всё завершается. Так что я думаю, что вы не туда копаете скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один способ решения с нерабочей Java 7 http://so4net.com/index.php/ru/blog/66-java-7-45